# Меры по защите 1С-Битрикс от взлома

Tags: безопасность, битрикс

Есть сайт, построенный на CMS 1С-Битрикс. Сайт вместе с админкой торчат в Интернет. Так как 1С-Битрикс - весьма популярная CMS, я ожидаемо беспокоюсь о возможности публикации серьезных уязвимостей в ней и возможности атаки script kiddies на сайт, так как определить, что сайт управляется именно этой CMS, несложно.

Какие можно предпринять меры для того, чтобы:

- затруднить автоматическое определение того, что сайт управляется CMS Bitrix?
- защитить админку Битрикса от брутфорса пароля администратора?

Пока что в голову пришло самое простое - ограничить доступ в админку по IP-адресам тех, кто будет админить сайт, однако это решение не универсально, и рано или поздно от него придётся отказаться - как только появится необходимость править материалы на сайте из произвольного места на планете 24/7, не заморачиваясь с прокси/VPN.

**Update:** позиция компании Битрикс по этому вопросу, как я понял из переписки с их саппортом, сводится к использованию возможностей модуля CMS 1С-Битрикс "Проактивная защита", позволяющему настроить ограничение доступа к админке по IP и двухфакторную авторизацию админов, а также многое другое, в т.ч. упомянающееся ниже в ответах. Однако мой вопрос скорее относится к защите на уровне сервера, не на уровне приложения. У этого решения, к тому же, есть большой недостаток - оно не универсально: модуль "Проактивная защита" включен не во все редакции (виды лицензий) данной CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Для интересующихся приведу использованный метод закрытия доступа в админку по IP: в корне сайта есть папка `bitrix`, содержащая код CMS и админки. В эту папку надо положить файл `.htaccess` следующего содержания:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 11.11.11.11
Allow from 22.22.22.22
```

В строчках, начинающихся с `Allow from`, указываются IP-адреса или подсети, которым разрешается доступ к админке.

Важная тонкость: помимо IP людей, которые должны иметь возможность работать с админкой, необходимо добавить также разрешение для того IP-адреса, с которого происходят внешние соединения с Интернет того сервера, где работает 1С-Битрикс, то есть, проще говоря, надо резрешить Битриксу доступ самому к себе. Если этого не сделать, то при диагностике в админке Битрикс будет ругаться на неработоспособность сокетов и не пройдёт диагностику полностью.

Приведённый способ ограничения доступа в админку не универсален. Он будет работать только если сервер работает под управлением Apache и только если Apache настроен образом, подразумевающим возможность управления доступом к сайту (Deny/Allow) через файлы `.htaccess`. Обычно (на популярных хостингах) так оно и есть, но в общем виде быть уверенным именно в такой настройке нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/). Есть платная подписка, которая как раз может предотвратить автоматическую атаку на сайт.

Работает по специальным правилам. Подписка - возможность получать эти правила. Если платить не хочется, то придется поискать на просторах интернет более подходящее, или составить самому.

Comment: что представляет собой "правило"? какую-то сигнатуру поведения клиента?

Comment: В основном паттерны, но можно сказать что это и есть поведение. Пример правил можно глянуть https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs

Comment: интересно, спасибо!

Comment: Вот ещё хорошая статья с картинками: http://habrahabr.ru/post/228103/

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую пройти онлайн-курс [Администратор.Модули](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=41), любезно предоставленный компанией 1С-Битрикс. Модуль проактивной защиты позволяет гибко настроить ограничения по IP не только глобально к сайту, но даже и к отдельным папкам. Битрикс умеет анализировать сколько хитов делает юзер и замораживать его и отсылать на указанную почту письмо со ссылками для действий над этим пользователем. От kiddy скриптов и для защиты среднего уровня этого более чем достаточно. У меня 5 активных интернет-магазинов сейчас крутятся на настройках "Проактивной защит" и нет ни взломов ни XSS атак. Атаки есть, но антивирус и фаервол справляются. Но разумеется, что должен быть и хороший качесвтенный хостер и провайдер, готовые выполнять по запросам антивирусные проверки.

Comment: Защищать приложение средствами самого этого приложения мне не кажется решением задачи в общем виде. Спасибо за ссылку, но вопрос остаётся открытым.

Comment: Кто будет сторожить сторожей? Извечный спор. Могу сказать только, что средство предлагаемое 1С-Битрикс достаточно хорошее чтобы избавить сайт от хакерских атак. У нас обычно все работает так. На сайте настраивается минимум средний уровень модуль в "Проактивной защите". При наличии тревожных сообщений в журнале обращаемся к хостеру и они выполняют сканирование. Так же используем "Поиск троянов" от Битркса [Поиск троянов](http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/bitrix.xscan/). Если найдете хорошее внешнее решение буду благодарен если поделитесь.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит также установить двухфакторную аутентификацию для админов. например от protectimus.com

Они позволяют генерировать одноразовые пароли для определенных IP, если перехватили пароль, то злоумышленник войти не сможет